# How to Ignore Not Existing Field in SOQL Dynamic Query

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

```
String objkey='Opportunity';
string recordID = '0061k000007Pyuf';
string soqlQueryCurrent='Id, Name, currency_Culture__c';
string queryStr ='SELECT '+soqlQueryCurrent+' FROM '+objkey+ ' WHERE id=:recordID' ; 
sObject sObjRecords = Database.query(string.escapeSingleQuotes(queryStr));
system.debug('sObjRecords: '+sObjRecords);
```

How to ignore the not existing field in soqlQueryCurrent, for example, currency_Culture__c field is not existing in the record so I want that when we run the query if we get not the existing field in the record so query executed for remaining field and ignore the not existing field.

Comment: If by non existing field you mean the field does not contain data or that the field does not exist at all? If the field does not exist on the object, then you can prepare the query using Describe methods

Comment: The field does not exist on the object

Comment: In that case you can use the describe classes http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2014/11/dynamic-apex-in-salesforce.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

You can just check for field existence before query.

```
Boolean fieldExists = Id.valueOf(recordID).getSobjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().containsKey('YOUR_FIELD_API_NAME');

String queryStr = 'SELECT Id' + (fieldExists ? ', YOUR_FIELD_API_NAME ' : '') + ' FROM ' + objkey + ' WHERE id = :recordID';
```